# non-fast forward error after rollback and rebase

Tags: git

What I am trying to do : Rolling back  `branch1` to some previous commit and then rebasing it on top of `master` branch.

There are two branches say `branch1` and `master`. I rolled back `branch1` to some previous commit using `reset --hard`.

After that I rebased branch1 on top of master. After resolving the conflicts, when I try to push, it gives non-fast forward error.

I tried `git push -f -u origin branch1`, `git push +branch1` but none of them worked. How to successfully push in this case ?

Comment: What exactly did "not work" with `git push -f -u origin branch1`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  And push was failed

Comment: So that's the explanation. You need to either edit the configuration of the repository on the server to allow non-fast-forward updates, or merge the remote changes before pushing again.

Comment: @mkrieger1 by merging the remote changes it means I can't really bring it back to previous commit  (since the new changes in remote will again get merged)?

Comment: Yes you can. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit, section "Undo published commits with new commits". You could also just push your rebased commits as a new branch that is different from `branch1`.

Comment: A hosting system (e.g., GitHub) can refuse a `git push` even with the `--force` flag. Git doesn't do that on its own though. So if it didn't work, you need to say *why* it didn't work: perhaps it was because GitHub (not Git) used a GitHub (not Git) rule to reject the push, in which case you have to do something on GitHub (not Git) to fix this.